# iPhone SDK: Image picker allows editing question

Tags: iphone, image, crop

In my app I use an image picker, and I can set the picker to allow editing, using:

```
self.imgPicker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
```

Now although this works, is there a way to customise the crop region this offers to a certain size?  I've been searching around on the net for it, and I don't seem to be getting anywhere.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, the `allowsImageEditing` property is deprecated (since iOS 3.1) - you should use `allowsEditing` instead.

However, to answer your question, there's no way to control the crop region that's supplied by the UIImagePickerController.

You could however create your own picker-style control that uses the Assets Library Framework to access images, etc. on the device, hence imposing your own limits and controls. (See the [Assets Library Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009730) for more information.) However, this is only available in iOS 4.0 and up and you'll need to re-invert a fairly large proportion of the wheel, so to speak.